# Update Items in Observable Array with RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

i have implemented an angular app which requests a list of items to fill a table.
In my service i have the following function which requests the list of items from the server:

```
requestPostingList(): Observable<Posting[]>
```

In the view the table subscribes to this Observable.

Dependig on a state variable in the Posting-Model I want poll the server for changes and update some (not all) items in the Posting[].
For that reason I have this function in my service class:

```
pollPostingState(postingId: string): Observable<Posting>
```

It polls every 2 secs on the server and if the state variable changes it emits a new Posting Object.

I need some kind of "merge mechanism" to update the items of the Posting[]. And this has to be done async, so I don't want to wait for all polls to finish. Every time a poll request finishes I want that in the UI, the corresponding row changes/updates.
So I need to emit an updated Posting[]....

How can I achieve this with RXJS?

thanks in advance

Edit:
How the table gets the data:

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Posting>([]);

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.postingService.requestPostingList()
    .subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
}
```

And in the HTML I bind dataSource to the mat-table

Comment: Could you post how the table puts the data on the screen?

Comment: added this information ...

Comment: How are you calling `pollPostingState`? Is that called for every `Posting`?

Comment: Something like `myService.pollPostingState(postingId).subscribe(posting => /* find the posting in this.dataSource.data and update it */)`. The binding with `mat-table` will do the re-rendering

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your application is defined. But you can use the `pipe` with `map` function. Could be something like this:

```
myService.pollPostingState(id)
    .pipe(
        map( response : Posting ) => {
            updateArray(response)
            return response;
        }
    ).subscribe(...)
```

This change will trigger `updateArray()` every time a new request is made to `pollPostingState` with a valid return.